# TSlint error "Expected property shorthand in object literal..." when declaring a variable to a object value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object like this:

```
   {
      element: 'tool-app',
      file: '/tool-app.js',
      icon: 'csr-icon',
      name: 'Planning view',
      id: 'planning-view'
    }
```

I want to store the value of icon in a variable and use it instead. First I define a constant:

```
const icon = 'csr-icon';
```

I then try to use the above icon to the object:

```
{
  element: 'tool-app',
  file: '/tool-app.js',
  icon: icon,   ///change here
  name: 'Planning view',
  id: 'planning-view'
}
```

It should be equal, but Tslint returns an error:

```
Expected property shorthand in object literal ('{icon}'). (object-literal-shorthand)tslint(1)
```

How come?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This error tells you that instead of `icon: icon,`, you can write only `icon` because the property name is the same as your const.

So your new object should look like this :

```
{
  element: 'tool-app',
  file: '/tool-app.js',
  icon,
  name: 'Planning view',
  id: 'planning-view'
}
```

This is called "shorthand" :)